# flash-all doesn't work, command not found - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

Trying to install the new Android 5.0 Preview. I first installed it a while ago on Windows with no problems. I switch over to Ubuntu a few weeks back, and now, after unlocking, I can't flash-all.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Had to actually extract the thing, navigate to it(I navigated to the zipped file, not the unzipped) with the `cd ~/...` command and run the `./flash-all.sh` file.